# Genymotion: how to load apk every time?

Tags: android, genymotion

I'm getting started with Android development and with Genymotion. It's difficult to get Genymotion to install a .apk and run it more than once. Here's what I'm doing:

1. Begin with Genymotion running.
2. Press Genymotion icon in Elipse.
3. See Genymotion Virtual Devices Manager. Note that **State** of my VM is **on**
4. Create a new Android Project
5. Press the green **Run** button
6. See **Run As** dialog. Select **Android Application**
7. See Android Device Chooser. Select **Genymotion_nexus_one**
8. See **hello world** app run. Press GM **home button**

From here if I change the app, it's **difficult to get the app to re-display** in the emulator:

1. Drag a button to activity_main.xml. Save.
2. Press the green **Run** button
3. **Nothing happens**

To get the app to re-display requires **jiggle the Handle** type actions:

1. If I **Clear the console log** or bring up the **GM Virtual Devices manager**, before I press the Run button, the app **will generally display in Genymotion**.

Any ideas how to make Genymotion behave without Jiggling the handle?

I'm running the latest SDK: 20131030 on OSX 10.7.5

Comment: More info: I've just noticed that if I right click the green Run button and hover over **Run As**, I see "(none available)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved:**

Since installing the adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030, I'd never right-clicked the Run button to display the drop-down menu there. Having done that once, pressing the Run button now brings up Android Device Chooser every time (as it should).

When I first ran into this problem, I reinstalled adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030 and Genymotion. I saw no change in behavior. This appears to be a minor bug in this version of adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030

Answer (score 64):

Drag drop apk on Genemotion emulator ,it will automatically installs and creates a shortcut.enjoy.

Comment: this doesn't work for an unsigned apk. That's what I'm stuck on right now.

Answer (score 5):

run in command-prompt :

```
adb install your_app_name.apk
```

:-)

Answer (score 0):

In **Android Studio**, if you run your project (shift+F10) when Genymotion virtual device is running; you'll see the device in connected devices list in *Select Deployment Target* window.